# spark: result of reduceByKey((x,y) => (x-y))

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There is a `RDD` to calculate the word count:

```
scala> demo2.collect()
res16: Array[String] = Array(hadoop,impala,hive, spark,storm, spark,hive,hive)
```

As shown, there are 3 `hive` and 2 `spark` in the rdd, but when I apply `-` operation:

```
scala> demo2.flatMap(x => x.split(",")).map(x => (x,1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => (x-y)).collect()
res25: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((hive,1), (impala,1), (spark,0), (hadoop,1), (storm,1))
```

As shown, `(spark,0)` is as expected, but `1-1-1` should equals `-1`, so why it returns `(hive,1)` rather than `(hive,-1)`?

Any help is appreciated.

The screenshot:
[image]

---

In addition, here is my code to create `demo2`:

```
val demo2 = sc.textFile("hdfs://my_namenode:8022/tmp/demo_name.csv")
```

And the content of `demo_name.csv`:

```
[root@test-04 tmp]# hdfs dfs -text /tmp/demo_name.csv
hadoop,impala,hive
spark,storm
spark,hive,hive
```

Comment: When I tried your code its returning -1 Are demo and demo2 same? I applied the the code for demo

Comment: @prms Hi, thansk for your reply and sorry for my mistake. The question is about `demo2`. I just modified my question and upload a picture of my result.

Comment: **reduce** is a *monoidal reduction*., thus it assumes the function is commutative and associative, meaning that the order of applying it to the elements is not guaranteed. Obviously, your function (x,y)=>(x-y) isn't commutative nor associative.

Comment: @eliasah I see. It executed `1 - (1 - 1) ` and then returns `1`. Thanks for your reply!